# Wrong use of inner join function / group function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem with my query:

I have two tables:

1. Customer
2. Subscriber

linked together by customer.id=subscriber.customer_id

in the subscriber table, I have records with id_customer=0 (these are email records, that do not have a full customer account)

Now i want to show how many customers I have per day, and how many subscribers with id_customer, and how many subscribers WITH id_customer=0 (emailonlies i call them)

Somehow, i cannot manage to get those emailonlies.
Perhaps it has something to do with not using the right join type.
When i use left join, i get the right amount of customers, but not the right amount of emailonlies. When I use inner join i get the wrong amount of customers. Am i using the group function correctly? i think it has something to do with that.

THIS IS MY QUERY:

```
   `   SELECT DATE(c.date_register),
COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS newcustomers,
COUNT(DISTINCT s.customer_id) AS newsubscribedcustomers,
COUNT(DISTINCT s.subscriber_id AND s.customer_id=0) AS emailonlies
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN subscriber s ON s.customer_id=c.id
GROUP BY DATE(c.date_register)
ORDER BY DATE(c.date_register) DESC
LIMIT 10
;`
```

Comment: In subscriber are you looking for `id_customer = 0` or `customer_id = 0` to determine emailonlies?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think in `DISTINCT s.subscriber_id AND s.customer_id=0`, it runs the `AND` before the `DISTINCT`, so the `DISTINCT` only ever sees true and false.

Why don't you just take

```
COUNT(DISTINCT s.subscriber_id) - (COUNT(DISTINCT s.customer_id) - 1)?
```

(The -1 is there because `DISTINCT s.customer_id` will count 0.)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, only risk is that i get no email onlies if there are no customers on this day, becuase of the left join. But this one works:

SELECT customers.regdatum,customers.customersqty,subscribers.emailonlies

FROM    (
    (SELECT DATE(c.date_register) AS regdatum,COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS customersqty
    FROM customer c
    GROUP BY DATE(c.date_register)
    ) AS customers

LEFT JOIN

```
(SELECT DATE(s.added) AS voegdatum,COUNT(DISTINCT s.subscriber_id) AS emailonlies
FROM subscriber s
WHERE s.customer_id=0
GROUP BY DATE(s.added)
) AS subscribers
```

ON customers.regdatum=subscribers.voegdatum
    )
ORDER BY customers.regdatum DESC
;